# Routing error on rails for a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error in Rails

```
Started GET "/jobs_folder/color-maps/mycolormap.txt" for 55.67.227.25 at 2015-10-12 20:00:51 -0700
Cannot render console from 55.67.227.25! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/jobs_folder/color-maps/mycolormap.txt")
```

I'm using a JavaScript/jQuery library where `mycolormap.txt` is a file that came with the library. I've placed the entire library as download at `vendor/assets/javascript`. I also added the following line to `application.js`

```
//can't disclose the library name
//=require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/downloaded/javascript/library
```

The file `mycolormap.txt` is in `vendor/assets/donwloaded/javascript/library/color-maps/mycolormap.txt`. But I'm calling the javascript code from an html.erb file which lies at `/my_application/app/views/jobs_folder/new.html.erb`.

So to conclude, `new.html.erb` is calling the javascript/jQuery library I downloaded, files there require the 'mycolormap.txt' file, but for some reason I don't have rails looking for that file in the right path (`my_application/vendor/assets/donwloaded/javascript/library/color-maps/mycolormap.txt`), rather, it is looking for it in some folder titled `jobs_folder/color-maps/mycolormap.txt` which I have no idea where it is (I've tried creating `jobs_folder/color-map/mycolormap.txt` in `my_application/public`, `my_application/app`, `my_application/app/assets`, and nothing helped this error). Also, I've tried moving the `.txt` file around to `assets`, `assets/images`, and a few other directories where Rails would look for stuff. My question is two-fold:

1) Where is Rails trying to find this file before going to `routes.rb`? where does it think `jobs_folder/color-maps/mycolormap.txt` would be? I need this answered so I can create a small prototype to test something with, even though copying the file there is not a long term solution

2) How do I include `my_application/vendor/assets/javascripts/downloaded/javascript/library/color-maps` as a directory to search for resources?

EDIT: I'm running the server using `rails server --binding=ipaddress` so it's running in development mode, not production

Comment: You can use `asset_path` to get the path do you need an link that points to a text file in a javascript lib? If you are using it as a data store why not use a JSON or JS file instead.

Comment: sorry what? I'm not clear. Where do I put `asset_path`, and what is the syntax? Also, I need the data to be in `.txt` files. Also, can you tell me where Rails is currently trying to find the `/jobs_folder` folder?